# In AWS Lambda function, what is the difference between deploy and publish?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In AWS Lambda function, what is the difference between deploy and publish?

When we only deploy, do the consuming services get to use the updated function (assuming they are pointing to latest function version)?

When we only publish, does it get auto deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where you are deriving your context for `deploy` and `publish`, normally `deploy` means redeploying your lambda with new code whereas `publish` is increasing your lambda version (not redeploying code).

Comment: 1) When we only deploy, do the consuming services get to use the updated function (assuming they are pointing to latest function version)?

Comment: 2) When we only publish, does it get auto deployed?

Comment: @variable - (1) if you deploy and your consuming services are referencing the LATEST version of lambda, then the new code will be consumed. (2) Publish will create a new version of lambda; you need your downstream services to reference the new version that gits published.

Comment: Regarding point 2, if downstream services are referencing LATEST version then new code will be consumed right?