# Terraform recreates API permissions for Lambda on each apply causing downtime (lambda module, serverless framework, VPC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, serverless-framework, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Lambda created via [terraform aws lambda module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest). It points to a versioned Lambda because I employ reserved concurrency. Also it resides in a VPC.

The config looks like so:

```
module "my-lambda" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version = "~> v1.45.0"

  function_name         = "${local.lambda_name}"
  description           = local.lambda_name
  handler               = "handler.handler"
  runtime               = "python3.8"
  hash_extra            = local.lambda_name
  attach_tracing_policy = true
  tracing_mode          = "Active"
  publish               = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
// required VPC security groups
  ]
  vpc_subnet_ids = var.private_subnet_ids
  source_path = [
    // ... abriged
  ]

  build_in_docker                           = true
  provisioned_concurrent_executions         = var.provisioned_concurrency_lambdas
  create_current_version_allowed_triggers   = true
  create_unqualified_alias_allowed_triggers = false

  allowed_triggers = {
    APIGateway = {
      service    = "apigateway"
      source_arn = "${module.my_api_gateway.this_apigatewayv2_api_execution_arn}/*"
    }
  }

  attach_policies = true
  policies = [
    // policies needed for a VPC lambda
  ]
}
```

I have found that in terraform plan, even if I do not do any changes and repeatedly issue `terraform plan`, this replacements are occurring - which leads to re-creation of API Gateway permissions and essentially a small downtime:

```
  # module.my_entire_api.module.my-lambda.aws_lambda_permission.current_version_triggers["APIGateway"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_lambda_permission" "current_version_triggers" {
      ~ id            = "APIGateway" -> (known after apply)
      ~ qualifier     = "1" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  #  module.my_entire_api.module.my-lambda.aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config.current_version[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config" "current_version" {
      ~ id                                = "env-my-lambda:1" -> (known after apply)
      ~ qualifier                         = "1" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

There are some other Lambdas that do not run in VPC. Presently I do not see such effect in these, while I am not completely sure that it never happens.

To be certain I do not care about concurrency config, as recreation of it does not cause downtime. But I want to configure the module such that aws_lambda_permission does not get re-created. How can I possibly do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was facing boils down to several things.

- When you do Provisioned Concurrency, you must "publish" your lambda so they have a proper version qualifier (something like "1" and NOT `$LATEST`), therefore Lambda permissions to allow Gateway to call Lambda are tied to specific Lambda version. When you make another version, these permissions are destroyed and created anew for the new Lambda version. `create_before_destroy` lifecycle flag can possibly help. I haven't seen these recreated for non-VPC lambdas when there are no changes; when Lambda is changed, there are few minutes between deleting and recreating the resrved concurrency and permissions inside Lambda for the API Gateway.
- VPC Lambdas, in addition, experience a recreation of concurrency and permissions even if Lambda not changed, Terraform bug https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17385.

Solution seems to be to not deal with permissions of Lambdas at all, but instead, provide API Gateway "credentials" (aka Role with Lambda InvokeFunction rights)  that allow it to call Lambdas. This way, when an AWS Gateway "integration" (= Lambda) is called, it assumes the Role. Permissions on Lambda side are not needed in such case. My tests show that in that case the sequence of updating the Lambda is correct: no unecessary recreations of resources for VPC lambdas, and when a Lambda is being updated, first a new version is deployed, and then API Gateway shifts to it (hence, no downtime happens). The production tests under certain load also confirmed that we do not see an outage in practice.

Here's the snippet for API Gateway configuration that permits Lambda invocations. It follows a recipe found at https://medium.com/@jun711.g/aws-api-gateway-invoke-lambda-function-permission-6c6834f14b61.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "api_gateway_credentials_call_lambda" {
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
  inline_policy {
    name = "permission-apigw-lambda-invokefunction"
    policy = jsonencode({
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          Effect   = "Allow",
          Action   = "lambda:InvokeFunction",
          Resource = "arn:aws:lambda:*:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:function:*"
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

Note that last `Resource =`  instruction would allow all Lambdas to be called by this Role. You might want to restrict these rights to a sub-set of lambdas for increased security and less of human error.

Having this Role set up, I configure API gateway using a popular Module [apigateway-v2 from serverless.tf framework](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/apigateway-v2/aws/latest):

```
module "api_gateway" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/apigateway-v2/aws"
  version = "~> 0.14.0"

  # various parameters ...

  # Routes and integrations
  integrations = {

    "GET /myLambda" = {
      integration_type        = "AWS_PROXY"
      integration_http_method = "POST"
      payload_format_version  = "2.0"
      lambda_arn              = my_lambda_qualified_arn
      # This line enables the permissions:
      credentials_arn         = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_credentials_call_lambda.arn
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An issue in `terraform-provider-aws` : [terraform-provider-aws 3.13.0 and later including 3.25.0 cause lambdas in a VPC to be updated on every apply #17385](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17385)

---

From the documentation [How to deploy and manage Lambda Functions?](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda#-how-to-deploy-and-manage-lambda-functions)

```
publish               = true
```

> Typically, Lambda Function resource updates when source code changes. If `publish = true` is specified a new Lambda Function version will also be created.

[publish flag](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/5a480b367ddef24e89cf9dc43be8a1e4f4408953/variables.tf#L94)

```
variable "publish" {
  description = "Whether to publish creation/change as new Lambda Function Version."
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}
```

[aws_lambda_permission](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/5a480b367ddef24e89cf9dc43be8a1e4f4408953/main.tf#L183)

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "current_version_triggers" {
  for_each = var.create && var.create_function && !var.create_layer && var.create_current_version_allowed_triggers ? var.allowed_triggers : {}

  function_name = aws_lambda_function.this[0].function_name
  qualifier     = aws_lambda_function.this[0].version
```

So every time you deploy a new version is being deployed which is referenced in the corresponding resource to update the policy. Hence it is triggering updates every time.

[In AWS Lambda function, what is the difference between deploy and publish?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64608429/2246345)

> Depending on where you are deriving your context for deploy and publish, normally deploy means redeploying your lambda with new code whereas publish is increasing your lambda version (not redeploying code).

Comment: But I do not update lambda itself, just run apply several times

Comment: @AskarIbragimov on every deployment it creates a new version.

Comment: Nope, it does not :)

Comment: @AskarIbragimov [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/blob/5a480b367ddef24e89cf9dc43be8a1e4f4408953/main.tf#L26) `aws_lambda_function` as per the [tf docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#publish). And the same thing is being show in the deployment logs you shared.

Comment: But it says “when source code changes” but mine isnt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231035/discussion-between-samtoddler-and-askar-ibragimov).

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17385

Comment: @AskarIbragimov partly the reason, I wasnt aware of the specific terraform provider versions you are using. I have added the explanation for the changes and not sure if you looked in the chatroom, I shared this as well <couple of dynamic configs as well> which miight be causing this.